# Joining two queries together

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have two queries that work separately but I'm not sure how to join them together...

`SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_date_time) AS int_month FROM my_table;`

This gets a list of all the months from my table as integers. But I want to convert the integers to the appropriate strings 'jan', 'feb', 'mar' etc.

And I have this to_char that takes an integer and gives back the string I need:

`SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (4::text, 'MM'), 'TMmon');`

So how do I insert the first query into where the '4' is in the second query? Something like...

`BEGIN;
    SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_date_time) AS int_month FROM my_table;
    SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (int_month::text, 'MM'), 'TMmon');
COMMIT;`

Comment: `SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_date_time) , 'MM'), 'TMmon');` ?

Comment: `SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_date_time) , 'MM'), 'TMmon') AS month FROM my_table;`

Comment: `ERROR:  function to_timestamp(double precision, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_date_ti...
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: `select to_char(my_date_time, 'TMmon') from my_table;`?